# Flattening and Reshaping image as Numpy Array to display

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing

I have an RGB image that I wanted to flatten to store in a single column of a numpy array with several such images in the columns. The issue is, when I store the numpy array and load it back the data is loaded properly and has the right values. But when I try to display the image, it displays a very oddly misshapen image. I do not understand where the issue is. Here is the code for storage and retrievel for reference.

```
npimg = imread(os.path.join(path, filename))
if cnt == 0:
    np.savetxt(os.path.join(path_save, 'image_1.txt'), npimg[:, :, 0].reshape((dimensions[0], dimensions[1])), fmt='%d')
    np.savetxt(os.path.join(path_save, 'image_2.txt'), npimg[:, :, 1].reshape((dimensions[0], dimensions[1])), fmt='%d')
    np.savetxt(os.path.join(path_save, 'image_3.txt'), npimg[:, :, 2].reshape((dimensions[0], dimensions[1])), fmt='%d')
    np.savetxt(os.path.join(path_save, 'image_flatten.txt'), npimg.flatten(), fmt='%d')
X[:, cnt] = npimg.flatten()
```

The above code is to individually save the image data before and after flattening. Note that the third dimension (RGB) is saved separately for proper visualisation.

```
current_row = X[:, 0]
np.savetxt(os.path.join(path, 'reverse_image_flatten.txt'), current_row, fmt='%d')
current_row = np.reshape(current_row, dimensions)
np.savetxt(os.path.join(path, 'reverse_image_1.txt'), current_row[:, :, 0].reshape((dimensions[0], dimensions[1])), fmt='%d')
np.savetxt(os.path.join(path, 'reverse_image_2.txt'), current_row[:, :, 1].reshape((dimensions[0], dimensions[1])), fmt='%d')
np.savetxt(os.path.join(path, 'reverse_image_3.txt'), current_row[:, :, 2].reshape((dimensions[0], dimensions[1])), fmt='%d')
plt.imshow(current_row)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

This is to retrieve the same data. It is observed that the data stored in image_1, 2 and 3 are same as reverse_iamge_1, 2 and 3. But when the image is displayed using imshow, the image is not proper. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: opencv library has plenty of functions to deal with this kind of issues...

Comment: The image is not proper how? Is your image `uint8` type?

Comment: It is uint8. When I try to _imshow_ the image using _matplotlib_, it is showing some garbage image while the original image is the face of a person.